# AS3: Only allow a certain number of a certain type of object into an Array

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, if-statement, classname

I want to find a way to only allow certain objects into an array that have a certain word in thier class name. Or at least find the optimal way of doing something like this. Heres the details. I have an Array that stores all the objects dropped into a cart.

`function addProductToArray (e:MouseEvent):void{
currMC = (e.target as MovieClip);
myCart.itemsInCart.push(currMC);
trace(myCart.itemsInCart);}`

If, for example, I drop an [object BreadGrain] and a [object PastaGrain].

`trace(myCart.itemsInCart);// would trace [object BreadGrain],[object PastaGrain]`.

Easy, no problems there. But what do I do if I only want to allow 2 objects with "Grain" in their Classname into the array? I want to do this so that the user can only drop 2 of each type of food into the 'cart'. The types of food are Grain, Fruit, Vegetable, Meats etc and I've appended the type of food to the end of the Classname, hopefully so that I can use it to detect what type of food it is and stop it from being added over the limit as well as displaying an error. i.e "You already have 2 Grain products".

I hope that makes sense. Anyway, i've found that works well to a degree:

```
if (currMC is BreadGrain) {
                myCart.itemsInCart.push(currMC);
            } else {
                // error message code here 
            }
```

BUT I have several products and I don't want to have to write a if/else or switch statement for them all. I was hoping to do this dynamically with something similar to:

```
//this is an example of the logic
if (currMC classNameContainsTheWord "Grain"  AND myCart.itemsInCart DoesNotContainMoreThan 2 Grain Objects) {
```

myCart.itemsInCart.push(currMC);
                } else {
                   // error message code here
                }

I'm stumped. Even just a "Dude, you are doing this all wrong" would help. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the class name of any object with the [getQualifiedClassName](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/utils/package.html#getQualifiedClassName%28%29) function. Then you could try to match strings agains a certain pattern, with a RegExp or you could also just check if the class name contains some substring.

That said, I think a better approach could be using either a common base class or an interface.

```
//  assuming your objects extend MovieClip
public class Grain extends MovieClip{

    public function Grain() {
        super();
    }

    public function someCommonMethodToAllGrains():void {

    }
}
```

or

```
//  It's customary to prefix interfaces name with an "I" in AS; 
//  I'm not doing it here so the code works for both a base class and an interface

public interface Grain {

    function someCommonMethodToAllGrains():void;
}
```

Then, if you went with the base class:

```
public class BreadGrain extends Grain {

    public function BreadGrain() {
        super();
    }

    override public function someCommonMethodToAllGrains():void {
        //  if this makes sense for your object...
        super.someCommonMethodToAllGrains();    
    }    

}

public class PastaGrain extends Grain {

    public function PastaGrain() {
        super();
    }

    override public function someCommonMethodToAllGrains():void {
        //  if this makes sense for your object...
        super.someCommonMethodToAllGrains();
    }    
}
```

Or, with the interface

```
public class BreadGrain extends MovieClip implements Grain {

    public function BreadGrain() {
        super();
    }

    public function someCommonMethodToAllGrains():void {

    }    

}

public class PastaGrain extends MovieClip implements Grain {

    public function PastaGrain() {
        super();
    }

    public function someCommonMethodToAllGrains():void {

    }    
}
```

If these objects are `MovieClips`, perhaps it's less tedious to use a base class, because otherwise you'd have to cast your objects back to `MovieClip` (or `DisplayObject`) any time you want to add them to the display list (or remove them). By the way, that's because someone at Adobe forgot to include an `IDisplayObject` interface and have the display list API accept objects that implemented this interface instead of a half-assed abstract class  that you can't derive directly anyway (a.k.a. `DisplayObject`); this would have make it easier to treat display objects as interfaces, but I digress).

Anyway, either with an interface or a common base class you could do your validation with the `is` operator, but you'd just have to check for one type: Grain.

```
if(theObject is Graing && theArray.lenght <= 2) {
    theArray.push(theObject);
}
```

You could also take this further and use a [Vector](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS3LCR/Flash_10.0/Vector.html) instead of an Array. A Vector works almost the same as an Array, but it's strictly typed, so you could do:

```
var items:Vector.<Grain> = new Vector.<Grain>();
items.push(grainObject);
```

You'll get a compile time error if you try to add an object that does not extend/implement Grain.

Vectors are available for Flash Player 10 and you'd need Flash CS4, though (if you're using the Flash IDE; otherwise, I think you'd need at least the 3.2 SDK to compile).

Comment: Was just about to suggest Interfaces and Vectors but you beat me to the punch.

Answer (score 0):

Hm. I think you're going to need something a bit more complex to make this work properly. You're actually asking a two-part question: how to keep track of stuff, and how to identify stuff. I'll start with the easy bit, keeping track.

DISCLAIMER: My AS3 is pretty rusty, but at least the theory should be sound, even if the implementation might be a bit off.

First, you'd want to define the limits for each type of food, thus:

```
var dctLimits = new Object(); // not really a Dictionary, but we'll use it like one
dctLimits[ "grain" ] = 3;
dctLimits[ "meat" ] = 5;
...
```

Then, you want to keep count of objects you're adding to your cart

```
var dctCount = new Object();
dctCount[ "grain" ] = 0;
dctCount[ "meat" ] = 0;
...
```

Then, when you add a new object, first check its type against the relevant count. If the counter is less than the limit, let it in and increment the counter:

```
var type:String = getFoodTypeForObject( currMc );
if( dctCount[ type ] < dctLimit[ type ] ){
    items.push( currMc );
    dctCount[ type ]++;
} else {
    // throw error
}
```

You'll notice that I've created an imaginary function, getFoodTypeForObject(). This is the trickier bit: identification.

You could implement your example logic like so:

```
function getFoodTypeForObject( currMc ){
    if( getQualifiedClassName( currMc ).indexOf( "Grain" ) > -1 ){
    return( "grain" );
    } else if( getQualifiedClassName( currMc ).indexOf( "Meat" ) > -1 ){
    return( "meat" );
    }
    ...
}
```

Where `classNameContainsTheWord` is achieved with a combination of `getQualifiedClassName` and `indexOf`, but better would be to use a common base class, as suggested by Juan Pablo Califano. I'd suggest a slightly different style though:

```
public class CartItem extends MovieClip{

    public var isGrain:Boolean;
    public var isMeat:Boolean;

    public function CartItem() {
        super();
    }
}
```

use that as the base Class for your cart item MCs, then set those boolean properties on the instances of MCs on your stage. Then, you can detect the type of something like this:

```
function getFoodTypeForObject( object ){
    if( object.isGrain ){
        return( "grain" );
    } else if( object.isMeat ){
        return( "meat" );
    }
    ...
}
```

Cleaner than all that classname business, and has the added benefit that you can set something's properties independent of its class name.

It's not perfect; for instance, you'd need something more advanced if you needed a lot of properties, but it should be enough for you to keep going.

Answer (score 0):

Uni had me doing other stuff for a while but finally I can get back into my game project.

I've got it working. I used Juan Pablo Califano's method. I did initially use Henry Cooke's because I wanted to get away with making a .AS file for each food (i.e. apple.as, cereal.as, bread.as, oranges.as). With Henry Cooke's method I created a

`var foodTypeLimit:Object = new Object();
foodTypeLimit["grain"]=2;
foodTypeLimit["fruit"]=2;

And var foodTypeCount:Object = new Object();
etc etc
`

For each food type. Then used the:

`var type:String = getFoodTypeForObject( currMc );
if( foodTypeCount[ type ] < foodTypeLimit[ type ] ){
    items.push( currMc );
    foodTypeCount[ type ]++;
} else {
    // throw error
}`

As suggested. The function returned the string and viola it worked fine. However because my foodTypeCount variables (for example **foodTypeCount["grain"]=0;**) was inside the function, every time the function called these were set to 0 so the increment never got above with each call. So I thought, ok, i'll put these foodTypeCount variables outside of the function along with the instantiation of the **var foodTypeCount:Object = new Object();** BUT NO, I kept getting the:

```
Error #1120: Access of undefined property foodTypeObject.
```

Even though it was right under the freakin declaration. I get i'm just too noob to understand why this is so. Anyway, for this reason (the lack of incrementation, which was essential to this function) I bit the bullet and used Juan Pablo Califano's way.

First I wrote out the classes like so:

```
public class Bread extends MovieClip implements Grain {

public function Bread() {
    super();
}

public function someCommonMethodToAllGrains():void {

}
```

}

And then added the interface

```
`public interface Grain {

    function someCommonMethodToAllGrains():void;
}
`
```

And now my function looks something like this:

```
if(currMC is Grain){
    if(grainCount<2){
        addProductToBasket();
        grainCount++;
    } else {
        notAllowed("Grain");
    }
 }

function addProductToBasket(){
    removeChild(currMC);
    basketArray.push(currMC);
    //remove listeners set mc to null etc
 }

function notAllowed(foodType:String){
    error.text="Sorry but you already have 2"+foodType+"products";
 }
```

I tried to put all this into a switch. For example:

```
switch(currMC){
   case is Grain:
   //do this
   break;
  }
```

The above implementation didn't work. Perhaps switch statements probably aren't meant to be used that way. idk. :S

Anyway, thanks for the really great answers guys, this is my favorite site to come to for answers to life the universe and everything.